# Hi My Dears, I was working on the Quadratic Equation Solution Technique Using Quantum?

Tags: qiskit

I was working on the Quadratic Equation Solution Technique Using Quantum ? But it seems to me that there might be no Quantum Benefit for it.

If anyone can kindly code this in a cleaver way , Please do kindly do it.[Please do kindly read this file to understand](https://github.com/anonto007/Quadratic-equation-Solution-by-Phase-kick-for-imaginary-roots-of-Quantum/blob/main/ax2%2Bbx%2Bc%3D0.pdf)

Comment: Why would you need to solve such a simple problem with quantum computing?

Answer (score 2):

Well, let the quadratic equation be in the form $$x^2+2bx+c=0 $$ You can write any quadratic equation in this form by dividing with the principle coefficient.

Therefore, what you are trying is to design a unitary map $U$ such that,
$$U\left(\begin{array}{c} b \\ c \end{array}\right)= \left(\begin{array}{c} -b+\sqrt{b^2-c^2} \\ -b-\sqrt{b^2-c^2} \end{array}\right)$$
But you can quickly check that $U$ doesn't preserve the norm. Therefore, $U$ is not a unitary matrix- so you cannot design such $U$ in quantum mechanics.

However, that's not a quantum problem. We use a quantum computer to solve problems that are very hard to solve using a classical computer.

Comment: What you have to say about this Matrix : about the final matrix in my Solution that i did derived, Also my Dear Brother, Please do kindly read the entire paper before commenting, Also as i told you earlier there might not be any Quantum benefit out of it, any way.. thanks my Dear Brother..

Comment: Please do kindly tell me, please do kindly look at my papers in the link, I am requesting you, cause I believe there are some basic miss-understanding in your concept.